# NSAttributedString not scrolling smoothly (disappearing/reappearing) in tableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, nsattributedstring

I have a tableview cell, and within it, I have a button.  Within this button, I am displaying an attributed text, which is dynamic. This works, however, when I scroll up and down, the text disappears and appears a quarter of a second later, and it is quite noticeable, especially when scrolling fast.

When debugging, I noticed if I commented out the lines `attString = [[NSMutableAttributed...` until the last `[attString appendAttributedString:[[...` method (below my comment), and set the title of the `profileIDButton` to `@"test"`, there was no issue when scrolling.  I believe that the allocation/initialization of `attString` is causing the scrolling issues.  How do I rid this disappearing and appearing a quarter of a second later behavior?  Is there any way to create an attributed string and append to it without allocating/initializing memory in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

```
//Within the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

    //  HERE IS WHERE I BELIEVE IS THE CAUSE OF TEXT DISAPPEARING DUE TO MEMORY ALLOCATION.
    attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    [attString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"@"  attributes:dict1]];
    [attString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:senderName   attributes:dict1]];
    [attString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" posted "      attributes:dict2]];
    [attString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:recepientName      attributes:dict2]];
    [attString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"."      attributes:dict2]];

    [cell.profileIDButton setAttributedTitle:attString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Top cells displaying this refreshing behavior when scrolling up
[image]

Comment: You should use the [time profiler](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode) to figure out where the slowdown, if any, is actually coming from. From your description of the problem, I suspect you may be reloading cells more than you think. The behavior you describe doesn't sound like it's memory-related to me, and if your strings were taking a long time to draw, you would be seeing stuttery scrolling, not text appearing and disappearing. Can you post a video of the problem occurring?

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like the labels are animating their opacity, or maybe the cell is changing selected or highlighted state. Is that possible?

Comment: maybe u can try move the attribute dictionary outside cellForRow coz it will keep making new one when loading each cell, in cellForRow set the string text only

Comment: You're doing a lot of repetitive work, try using instance variables for `color#`, `font#` and `dict#`. That would be a first shot, use _Instruments_ to profile your app and see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Here is a video of it.  I slowed the animation down so you can get a good look at whats going on.  If it was the reloading of the cells, then the right image would be displaying that behavior too.  https://youtu.be/pxJsaOJIfJA

Comment: I dont think the animating of the opacity is an issue, because I commented out the entire section below my comment and set the button title to @"test", and it did not display that behavior.

Comment: did you try profiling the app and seeing which statements are slowing you down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the button type to 'UIButtonTypeCustom' maybe work.

Comment: WOW THIS WAS THE ANSWER!  I never thought that the fix would be this simple.. I am shocked.

Comment: May I know the rationale for this?